# upload data from excel to access using java

Tags: java, apache

Can anyone give me some idea about uploading data from excel to access database using java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll definitely want to check out [Apache POI - Java API To Access Microsoft Format Files](http://poi.apache.org/). You'll likely find the Excel bindings you need there. For MS Access, you'll want a JDBC Driver which you can [find on Sun's website](http://developers.sun.com/product/jdbc/drivers). Then you can just write the glue code.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to use Java for that?  You can link Excel and Access data directly:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HP010950951033.aspx

Comment: i need it as for my project requirement

Answer (score 1):

I've used [POI](http://poi.apache.org/) before to read and write Excel files. Once you got the data, use JDBC (maybe the JDBC/ODBC bridge) to load it into Access.

Comment: Asaph mentioned a JDBC driver for Access. A dedicated driver would definitely be preferable over the JDBC/ODBC bridge.

Comment: Yep you should definitely get you hands on a appropriate JDBC driver, I've used the JDBC/ODBC bridge before in combination with an Access database and alot of pretty basic JDBC things are unsupported (if I remember correctly even transactions were not supported).